# Export blob column from mysql dB to disk and replace it with new file name

Tags: mysql, blob, dbm

So I'm working on a legacy database, and unfortunately the performance of database is very slow. Simple select query can take up to 10 seconds in tables with less than 10000 record.

So i tried to investigate problem and found out that deleting column that they have used to store files (mostly videos and images) fix the problem and improve performance a lot.

Along with adding proper indexes I was able to run exact same query that used to take 10-15sec to run in under 1sec.

So my question is. Is there any already existing tool or script I can use to help me export those blobs (videos) from database and save the to disk and update row with new file name/path on file system?

If not is there any proper way to optimize database so that those blob would not impact performance that much?

**Hint** some one clients consuming this database use high level orms so we don't have much control on queries orm use to fetch rows and its relations. So I cannot optimize queries directly.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 INTO DUMPFILE 'name.png';`

How about this way?

These is also `INTO_OUTFILE`instead of `INTO_DUMPFILE`

> 13.2.10.1 SELECT ... INTO Statement The SELECT ... INTO form of SELECT enables a query result to be stored in variables or written to a file:
>
> SELECT ... INTO var_list selects column values and stores them into
>   variables.
>
> SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE writes the selected rows to a file. Column and
>   line terminators can be specified to produce a specific output format.
>
> SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE writes a single row to a file without any
>   formatting.

Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html